# How to add a parameter to a reference to a function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm creating a plugin for jQuery, and one of the methods have an object with the options:

`opts.events` => Array of events in the format:

`name => e.g."click","mouseover"...`
`function => ref to function`

**The code below adds the listener**

```
myParam = "Test"
for event in opts.events
    google.maps.event.addDomListener btnElement, event.name, event.function
```

### Problem

When calling the function `event.function` should send `myParam` as a reference, along with the parameters of the function

**I thought of something like:**

```
myParam = "Test"
for event in opts.events
    google.maps.event.addDomListener btnElement, event.name, event.function.call(myParam)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as sending `myParam` as a reference to the string, that's already taken care of by Javascript. The bad news is that strings in Javascript are immutable, meaning you can not change it, assuming that is why you wanted to pass it as a reference.

As to your coding problem, here's a solution:

```
myParam = "Test"
for event in opts.events
    google.maps.event.addDomListener btnElement, event.name, ->
        event.function myParam
```

The `->` creates an anonymous function that gets passed, which already knows about your `myParam` variable through it's closure. This function calls the event.function, passing `myParam` as you wanted. `call`/`apply` is something else and probably not needed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're misusing `.call`—its first argument is a context. If you're trying to pass the current context to the function, for instance, you would write `event.function.call(this, myParen)`.

As to your main problem, what you need to do is wrap the function in another function:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener btnElement, event.name, => event.function.call this, myParam
```

If context doesn't matter in `event.function`, you can cut that down to

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener btnElement, event.name, -> event.function(myParam)
```